# Computational complexity of nested for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

When I run this code for the n value of 5, I get 25. When I run the code with n value of 3, I got 9. I understand there's an n^2 relation between input and output, but why for the value of 5, I get n^2 and how? Can anybody explain it further?

```
n = input()
n = int(n)

count = 0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        count += 1

print("n =",n, "count =",count)
```

Comment: The outer loop runs `n` times. For each time the outer loop runs, the inner loop runs `n` times. That gives `n * n = n^2`.

Comment: 5 (outer loop iterations) * 5 (inner loop iterations per outer loop iteration) = 25 (total inner loop iterations). Why do you find it odd? What number did you expect? You seem to know that you should have `n^2` iterations in total but then seem surprised when you in fact get `n^2`. The question is unclear.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. It's clear now. That means for n = 5, it runs 5 times for 0,1,2,3,4 and by adding all of them the count is 25.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` loops execute their loop body once for each value in the iterable. Here the iterable in both loops is a `range(n)` object, which produce a sequence of `n` values from `0` through to `n - 1`, so the loop body is executed `n` times.

For the inner loop, the loop body is `count += 1`, but the inner loop is itself nested inside an outer loop.

You could unroll the loops and copy their body `n` times. Let's fill in `n = 3` into the code:

```
count = 0

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        count += 1
```

For `n = 3`, the `range()` object produces `0`, `1` and `2`, which the outer loop assigns to `i` each time. Unrolling the outer loop can then be done by replacing the loop with manual `i = <value>` assignments and copying the inner loop below it (adjusting the indentation):

```
count = 0

i = 0
for j in range(3):
    count += 1

i = 1
for j in range(3):
    count += 1

i = 2
for j in range(3):
    count += 1
```

We can then further unroll the inner loops, assigning to `j`:

```
count = 0

i = 0
j = 0
count += 1
j = 1
count += 1
j = 2
count += 1

i = 1
j = 0
count += 1
j = 1
count += 1
j = 2
count += 1

i = 2
j = 0
count += 1
j = 1
count += 1
j = 2
count += 1
```

So for `n = 3`, we had to unroll the outer loop into 3 separate inner loops, then unroll each inner loop into 3 more `count += 1` calls, totalling 3 times 3 == 9 `count += 1` calls.

Generalizing that to any `n`, means you get `n * n` or `n` to the power 2 iterations of the innermost loop code, `count += 1`.

Of course, for more complex code it becomes impractical to copy out the loop body multiple times just to work out what is going on. You’d instead have Python tell you what it is doing, by adding `print(f"i = {i}")` and `print(f"j = {j}")` statements or by stepping through the code with a debugger.